# Java access data in JSON string

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have problems accessing data in a JSON string. What am I doing wrong?

Working:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("JSON-STRING");
JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("weather");
System.out.println(arr.getJSONObject(0).get("description"); >> clear sky
```

Not working:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("JSON-STRING");
JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("main");
System.out.println(arr.getJSONObject(0).get("temp"); >> 285.15
```

Exception:

> ```
> org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["main"] is not a JSONArray.
>     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:622)
>     at main.SmartHomeBot.onUpdateReceived(SmartHomeBot.java:47)
>     at org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession$HandlerThread.run(DefaultBotSession.java:274)
> ```

The JSON-String:

```
{
    "coord": {
        "lon": 6.55,
        "lat": 51.27
    },
    "weather": [{
            "id": 800,
            "main": "Clear",
            "description": "clear sky",
            "icon": "01d"
        }
    ],
    "base": "stations",
    "main": {
        "temp": 285.15,
        "pressure": 1034,
        "humidity": 30,
        "temp_min": 285.15,
        "temp_max": 285.15
    },
    "visibility": 10000,
    "wind": {
        "speed": 2.6
    },
    "clouds": {
        "all": 0
    },
    "dt": 1492705200,
    "sys": {
        "type": 1,
        "id": 4909,
        "message": 0.2825,
        "country": "DE",
        "sunrise": 1492662386,
        "sunset": 1492713582
    },
    "id": 2808559,
    "name": "Willich",
    "cod": 200
}
```

Comment: `{..}` represents object, `[..]` represents array. As you see `"main": {...}` holds an object not an array, which is why `getJSONArray("main")` is causing problems.

Comment: Voting to close as typo. Nothing more to explain here.

Comment: JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(JSON-STRING);
          JSONObject arr = obj.getJSONObject("main");       
          System.out.println(arr.get("temp")); fixed it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because `weather` is the array of the multiple `weather`  and `main` is the single object.

Difference between both is shown below:

```
 "weather": [{
        "id": 800,
        "main": "Clear",
        "description": "clear sky",
        "icon": "01d"
    }
],
```

and

```
"main": {
    "temp": 285.15,
    "pressure": 1034,
    "humidity": 30,
    "temp_min": 285.15,
    "temp_max": 285.15
},
```

So in the JSON `"weather" : [{....}, {....}, {....}]`   `[]` show that `weather` is the array.

Answer (score 0):

In your parent json value for key "weather" represents a JSONArray but value for key "main" represents a JSONObject not JSONArray.

To fetch the data from JsonObject you should do like below

```
JSONObject mainObj = obj.getJSONObject("main");
System.out.println(mainObj.get("temp"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String jsonobj = "{\n    \"coord\": {\n        \"lon\": 6.55,\n        \"lat\": 51.27\n    },\n    \"weather\": [{\n            \"id\": 800,\n            \"main\": \"Clear\",\n            \"description\": \"clear sky\",\n            \"icon\": \"01d\"\n        }\n    ],\n    \"base\": \"stations\",\n    \"main\": {\n        \"temp\": 285.15,\n        \"pressure\": 1034,\n        \"humidity\": 30,\n        \"temp_min\": 285.15,\n        \"temp_max\": 285.15\n    },\n    \"visibility\": 10000,\n    \"wind\": {\n        \"speed\": 2.6\n    },\n    \"clouds\": {\n        \"all\": 0\n    },\n    \"dt\": 1492705200,\n    \"sys\": {\n        \"type\": 1,\n        \"id\": 4909,\n        \"message\": 0.2825,\n        \"country\": \"DE\",\n        \"sunrise\": 1492662386,\n        \"sunset\": 1492713582\n    },\n    \"id\": 2808559,\n    \"name\": \"Willich\",\n    \"cod\": 200\n}";
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonobj);
JSONObject jsonObject = obj.getJSONObject("main");
System.out.println(jsonObject.get("temp"));
```

Comment: A line that is nearly 900 characters long. Isn't there a better way?